# UIImageOrientation with camera

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, xcode8, uiimageorientation

This is the code of my camera, change the front camera to the rear camera, if I take a picture with the back camera, the orientation of the photo is good (original), but if i take a photo with the front camera get the image with the bad orientation.

```
class TakeSelfieViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

var sessionOutputSetting = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG])

var toggle = false

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tempImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var adorButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = adorButton.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    adorButton.addSubview(blurEffectView)

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    pickCamera(which: toggle)

}

func pickCamera(which: Bool) {

    if (which == true) {

        let deviceDescovery = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.back)

        print("back camera")

        startCamera(deviceDesc: deviceDescovery!)

        toggle = true

    } else if (which == false) {

        let deviceDescovery = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)

        print("front camera")

        startCamera(deviceDesc: deviceDescovery!)

        toggle = false

    }

}


func startCamera(deviceDesc: AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession!) {

    for device in (deviceDesc.devices)! {


        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {

            do {

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
                        captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)


                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait


                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                        print("ADD Back")

                    } else { print("Cannot add input - back") }

                }

            } catch {

                print("Error")

            }

        } else if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front) {

            do {

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                print(input)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {

                    captureSession.addInput(input)

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
                        captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)


                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait


                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                        print("ADD Front")

                }

                } else { print("Cannot add input - front") }

            } catch {

                print(error)

            }
        }
    }
}

func didPressTakePhoto() {
    if let videoConnection = photoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG])
        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

    }
}

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

    let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer!, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer)
    let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
    let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

    let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
    self.tempImageView.image = image
    self.tempImageView.isHidden = false
    self.yellowButton.isHidden = true
    self.toggleAction.isHidden = true
    self.adorButton.isHidden = true
    print("Hola")
}

var didTakePhoto = Bool()

@IBOutlet weak var yellowButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var toggleAction: UIButton!

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if didTakePhoto {
        tempImageView.isHidden = true
        yellowButton.isHidden = false
        toggleAction.isHidden = false
        adorButton.isHidden = false
        didTakePhoto = false
        print("")

    }
}

@IBAction func yellowPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    captureSession.startRunning()
    didTakePhoto = true
    didPressTakePhoto()
    print("")
}

@IBAction func toggleCamera(_ sender: Any) {

    if (toggle == false) {

        print("Changing to back camera")

        let currentCameraInput: AVCaptureInput = captureSession.inputs[0] as! AVCaptureInput

        captureSession.removeInput(currentCameraInput)

        toggle = true

        pickCamera(which: toggle)

    } else if (toggle == true) {

        print("Changing to front camera")

        let currentCameraInput: AVCaptureInput = captureSession.inputs[0] as! AVCaptureInput

        captureSession.removeInput(currentCameraInput)

        toggle = false

        pickCamera(which: toggle)

    }

}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {

    return true

}
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Images taken with front camera are mirrored, when you take a picture the image orientation is taken inside the EXIF dictionary of it, or passed inside a dictionary of metadata.

Most of the time when you pass it around as JPG or PNG this value is not taken into account if you don't deal directly with it.
You should experience a similar problem if you take a picture in landscape.

In your capture method, it seems that you are forcing orientation to a fixed value when you should take care of it.

Comment: your post is not accessible